# What does this sticker on the back of my passport mean?

Tags: usa, passports, airport-security, paperwork

I am currently travelling in the USA and when checking in on the boarding flight to enter the country, the security personnel attached a small yellow-white sticker to my passport (see a somewhat terrible photo below):

[image]

This happened on Stockholm Arlanda (ARN) when I was waiting in queue for check in, and by one of the security personnel that inquired about my business in USA.

Does this have any special meaning? Why would they do it anyway? Can I take it away before I leave the country, or should it stay on?

Comment: I got the same when travelling from Amsterdam... and TSA checked my bag.. I figured it was bc I was a 20 y/o travelling in Holland... self explanatory..

Comment: @user22315 TSA is a US agency; the security screening at Schiphol is done by some other organization.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can give an answer to this because this happens to me very regularly, for a good reason.

Typically for holders of US / UK / European / Australian / NZ passports, a wide range of countries do not require a visa in advance, or often issue them on arrival. If you're travelling within North America or Europe where these visa rules are well-known, an airline simply checks you in.

The security clearance sticker is used whenever the airline has a liability to carry you back to your origin in case you're denied entry. Many countries require you to pass through passport control both when leaving and entering the country. In UK and Europe however, passport control is done at many airports only when you *enter* the country, not when you leave.

I hold an Indian passport, which means that for most destinations I need to get a visa. If I ever end up in a situation where I go to a country and I'm denied entry, the airline is obligated to fly me back. For this reason, airlines run their visa checks for passport holders whom they *know* need a visa, and upon validation, they paste this sticker. Don't take this sticker off until you reach your destination because in case of any queries - for instance, staff at the boarding gate may want to confirm your visa status - airline staff check for this sticker to see whether you've been cleared for boarding.

ICTS International (that's the corporate name; at airports, I've seen employees wearing badges that read 'i-Sec') is one of those companies that a lot of airlines hire out this task to; another company that airlines outsource this task to is CheckPoint. Some airlines carry out their own checks and use the same sticker system too.

Comment: Not sure of this. I have 2 passports: an EU and a Canadian one. I got a new Canadian passport while on the EU, and while boarding on a (direct) Air Canada flight from Venice to Toronto they applied the sticker. By having a Canadian passport I wasn't risking being rejected in any way (that was my outgoing flight)

Comment: I swear to god Mr. Banerjee if I would have not read this here today, I would have died without knowing this beautiful piece of information. Plus, I hate those stickers, so I keep removing them. Guess I gotta be more careful! +1 Thanks!

Comment: It's nothing to do with needing or not needing a visa. I get those stickers on my passport every time I fly from the UK to north America even though, as a UK citizen, I don't need a visa.  I don't remember if I get them while flying within the EU.

Comment: Don't forget about Securitas.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it may be that it confirms that they've checked you against the entry requirements regardless of what those requirements may be in your case.  I have two passports, and recently when I was boarding a plane I showed the one I hadn't checked in with.  The guy was very concerned until I fished the other passport out from the bottom of my pocket.

Comment: @Qualcuno they still check some things about your passport, though, like its validity dates, and the sticker could still be showing that this check (or any other passport-related procedures that may be required) has been performed.

Comment: Airport and transport security is unrelated to immigration and visas. Amazing the amount of stuff people can make up (and believe) without any research and sourcing. Now even outside fakebook.

Comment: @Ankur Could you also add information about why there are green, yellow and red stickers? I always receive a green one and a friend of mine always gets a red one and has the priviledge of going through a secondary security screening.

Comment: Also, even if one were flying directly to their country of citizenship, they might have an onward flight to somewhere else for which they _would_ need to verify documents at check-in.  In that situation it might be easier to give a sticker to everyone.

Answer (score 14):

It says "ICTS", so this was attached by [the company providing security services for certain airports in US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICTS_International).
This is probably to mean that you have undergone security checks and had passport checked there.
I had similar stickers attached to my passport when travelling in China, as well.